# Does the nullish coalescing operator (??) in TypeScript have more browser support than JavaScript's?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser-support

In JavaScript, [browser support for the nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#Browser_compatibility) (??) is limited to newer browsers (e.g. Chrome 80, Edge 80, Firefox 72). Since TypeScript is converted to JavaScript, do nullish coalescing operators go through some sort of conversion as well, sort of like a polyfill?

Comment: Why not use one and find out with "view source"?

Comment: Well Typescript doesn't really have *any* browser support; it's translated to JavaScript at build time. Whether they're transformed into something else depends on how you target your Typescript build.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> do nullish coalescing operators go through some sort of conversion as well, sort of like a polyfill?

The TypeScript gets transpiled to JavaScript. As for now, yes, nullish coalescing will be transpiled, along with all the other syntax that isn't yet supported by your `target` ES version in your tsconfig.

For example, in TS:

```
obj.foo ?? 5;
```

gets transpiled to

```
"use strict";
var _a;
(_a = obj.foo) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : 5;
```

Similarly, the exponentiation operator:

```
3 ** 5
```

gets transpiled to

```
Math.pow(3, 5);
```

if your target is ES2015 or earlier. (The exponentiation operator was introduced in ES2016.) Otherwise, if your target is ES2016 or greater, it does not get transpiled.

Comment: Thank you for being polite, helpful, and descriptive.

Comment: Is there a way to patch browsers that do not support the nullish coalescing operator but can run GreaseMonkey scripts? I believe this new-fangled thing is the reason I get "`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'`" on StackOverflow. =(

Comment: @user21820 Not really, you can't patch *syntax* the way you can patch (polyfill) objects and method. But if, in your tsconfig, you set a target below ES2020 or so, optional chaining and nullish coalescing should be transpiled for older browsers.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: What if I use the `beforescriptexecute` event? Can I patch each script then?

Comment: @user21820 No, that event is non-standard and doesn't work on Chrome, Edge, Opera, Safari, or pretty much anything except Firefox. You should make sure the code is compatible *before* inserting (ideally, when you're serving it to users), not during insertion.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: But I am the *user*, and all I want to patch is *my* browser. I can't control the codebase on SO webpages, but I'd like to know whether I can patch the code anyway before executing it. I can successfully block scripts by listening for that event, but I don't know how to change them.

Comment: @user21820 The *best* approach would be to ask the script-writer to provide a more compatible version of the script. If that's not possible, you can transpile the code yourself by putting it through Babel: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: As I said, the scripts are the ones running on *this website*! How do I patch the scripts from SO? I don't see how transpilers help here.

Comment: @user21820 Ah, sorry I thought you were referring to a userscript. But wow - https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=c8f25bf6ebe0:formatted Stack Exchange is using it in production now, I see. That's a bad decision IMO, though it's in line with the browsers they officially support: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161 How to fix it depends on your browser. In Chrome, you'd need Chrome Local Overrides. Not sure about other browsers. A more general solution will involve Fiddler. This is an interesting issue that could easily stand as its own question.

Comment: It's *possible* to also fix it with your own userscript, but a lot more convoluted.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I'd prefer a userscript solution. All I need is an example of how to modify scripts efficiently, as I tried it before and it crashed so I don't know whether it's because the script is too long or something else. Any suggestion or recommended reference for doing this? Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't get a userscript to do what I asked you above, but recently SO stopped relying on that new feature so...